# How can I create a wireless network with an access point across the street?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking

What I'm looking at doing is setting up a network for two locations.  They are separated by about 100 feet.  I'm looking for a wireless device(s) that transport the signal from my house to my garage.  I'm really against running wire, and a wireless solution sounds like the best.

I have a linksys router in my home, and looking for some device that I can run a cable to, and point it at my garage.  This could be through a window or something.

Just looking for ideas or comments from anyone whos setup this type of thing before.

Thanks!

- Would 100ft be covered by a standard wireless router, or would I need a specific type? (G, N, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a wireless router in bridged mode (many routers don't have it in their original firmware, but if it is supported  by some of the opensource firmwares, it can be flashed and you can use the bridging capabilities).

OOS Firmwares: [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/), [openwrt](http://openwrt.org/), [tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato). Check their supported devices lists.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you Linksys router is not also wireless router, then you'll want to look into getting a WAP ([Wireless Access Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point)) to "convert" a wired end into wireless.

If that isn't strong enough you can look into getting another WAP and putting it in "repeater' mode which will pick up a wireless network and then rebroadcast it to get further reach.  Most/many WAPs have this optional functionality.

Aim to get a WAP with a standard, detachable antenna in case you find to need to change the antenna to something a little better than the usual one included, to get your distance across the yard (I.E. an omni-directional antenna you can point at the building your aiming for).